# Please Help: IPython for Emacs on Windows crashes

Tags: python, windows, emacs, ipython

**Questions Update: Why there is no In[1]: prompt?**

Please see the following output of IPython command line in Emacs.

```
Python 2.5.2 (r252:60911, Feb 21 2008, 13:11:45) [MSC v.1310 32 bit (Intel)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 0.10 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object'. ?object also works, ?? prints more.


import sys
sys.path
Out[4]: 
['',
 'C:\\Python25\\scripts',
 'C:\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages\\pyflakes-0.4.0-py2.5.egg',
 'C:\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages\\pylint-0.21.3-py2.5.egg',
 'C:\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages\\logilab_astng-0.20.3-py2.5.egg',
 'C:\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages\\logilab_common-0.52.0-py2.5.egg',
 'C:\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages\\unittest2-0.5.1-py2.5.egg',
 'C:\\Python25\\Lib\\site-packages\\pyflakes',
 'C:\\Python25\\Lib\\site-packages\\Pymacs',
 'C:\\Python25\\Lib\\site-packages\\rope',
 'C:\\Python25\\Lib\\site-packages\\ropemacs',
 'C:\\Python25\\Lib\\site-packages\\ropemode',
 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\python25.zip',
 'C:\\Python25\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python25\\lib',
 'C:\\Python25\\lib\\plat-win',
 'C:\\Python25\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Python25',
 'C:\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
 'C:\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython/Extensions',
 u'C:\\Home\\_ipython']
```

---

Hi,

I am using IPython 0.10, Python 2.5, and EmacsW32 23.1 and ipython.el Rev.2927 on Windows XP. It always crashes when I invoke python-shell in Emacs. Could somebody helps on this problem? Thanks a lot!

**update**: I've tried the fix https://bugs.launchpad.net/ipython/+bug/290228 , but it doesn't help.

IPython crashes with the following long debugging information:

> ERROR: An unexpected error occurred
>   while tokenizing input The following
>   traceback may be corrupted or invalid
>   The error message is: ('EOF in
>   multi-line statement', (14, 0))
>
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError
>   Python 2.5.2: C: \Python25\python.exe
>                                                      Thu Sep 30 14:00:08 2010 A problem
>   occured executing Python code.  Here
>   is the sequence of function calls
>   leading up to the error, with the most
>   recent (innermost) call last.
>
> c:\Python25\Scripts\ipython-script.py
>   in ()
>         1
>         2
>         3
>         4
>         5
>         6
>         7
>   ----> 8
>           global load_entry_point = 
>         9 #!C:\Python25\python.exe
>        10 # EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'ipython==0.10','console_scripts','ipython'
>        11 **requires** = 'ipython==0.10'
>        12 import sys
>        13 from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
>        14
>        15 sys.exit(
>        16    load_entry_point('ipython==0.10',
>   'console_scripts', 'ipython')()
>        17 )
>        18
>        19
>        20
>        21
>        22
>        23
>        24
>        25
>        26
>        27
>        28
>        29
>        30
>        31
>
> C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\ipython-0.10-py2.5.egg\IPython\ipapi.pyc
>   in launch_new_instance(user_ns=None,
>   shellclass=None)
>       541
>       542     def check_hotname(self,name):
>       543         if name in self.hotnames:
>       544             self.debug_stack( "HotName '%s' caught" % name)
>       545
>       546
>       547 def launch_new_instance(user_ns =
>   None,shellclass = None):
>       548     """ Make and start a new ipython instance.
>       549
>       550     This can be called even without having an already initialized
>       551     ipython session running.
>       552
>       553     This is also used as the egg entry point for the 'ipython'
>   script.
>       554
>       555     """
>   --> 556     ses = make_session(user_ns,shellclass)
>       557     ses.mainloop()
>       558
>       559
>       560 def make_user_ns(user_ns = None):
>       561     """Return a valid user interactive namespace.
>       562
>       563     This builds a dict with the minimal information needed to
>   operate as a
>       564     valid IPython user namespace, which you can pass to the
>   various embedding
>       565     classes in ipython.
>       566
>       567     This API is currently deprecated. Use
>   ipapi.make_user_namespaces() instead
>       568     to make both the local and global namespace objects
>   simultaneously.
>       569
>       570     :Parameters:
>       571         user_ns : dict-like, optional
>
> C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\ipython-0.10-py2.5.egg\IPython\ipapi.pyc
>   in make_session(user_ns=None,
>   shellclass=None)
>       669
>       670 def make_session(user_ns = None, shellclass = None):
>       671     """Makes, but does not launch an IPython session.
>       672
>       673     Later on you can call obj.mainloop() on the returned object.
>       674
>       675     Inputs:
>       676
>       677       - user_ns(None): a dict to be used as the user's namespace
>   with initial
>       678       data.
>       679
>       680     WARNING: This should *not* be run when a session exists
>   already."""
>       681
>       682     import IPython.Shell
>       683     if shellclass is None:
>   --> 684         return IPython.Shell.start(user_ns)
>       685     return shellclass(user_ns = user_ns)
>       686
>       687
>       688
>       689
>       690
>       691
>       692
>       693
>       694
>       695
>       696
>       697
>       698
>       699
>
> C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\ipython-0.10-py2.5.egg\IPython\Shell.pyc
>   in start(user_ns=None)    1226
>   th_mode = special_opts.pop()    1227
>   except KeyError:    1228
>   th_mode = 'tkthread'    1229
>   return th_shell[th_mode]    1230
>   1231    1232 # This is the one which
>   should be called by external code.
>   1233 def start(user_ns = None):
>   1234     """Return a running shell
>   instance, dealing with threading
>   options.    1235    1236     This is a
>   factory function which will
>   instantiate the proper IPython shell
>   1237     based on the user's threading
>   choice.  Such a selector is needed
>   because    1238     different GUI
>   toolkits require different thread
>   handling details."""    1239    1240
>   shell = _select_shell(sys.argv)
>   -> 1241     return shell(user_ns = user_ns)    1242    1243 # Some
>   aliases for backwards compatibility
>   1244 IPythonShell = IPShell    1245
>   IPythonShellEmbed = IPShellEmbed
>   1246 #************************ End of
>   file 
>   ***************************    1247    1248    1249    1250    1251    1252
>   1253    1254    1255    1256
>
> C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\ipython-0.10-py2.5.egg\IPython\Shell.pyc
>   in
>   **init**(self=, argv=None,
>   user_ns=None, user_global_ns=None,
>   debug=1, shell_class=)
>        58 # Default timeout for waiting for multithreaded shells (in seconds)
>        59 GUI_TIMEOUT = 10
>        60
>        61
>
> ## -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> ```
>  62 # This class is trivial now, but I want to have it in to publish a
> ```
>
> clean
>        63 # interface. Later when the internals are reorganized, code that
>   uses this
>        64 # shouldn't have to change.
>        65
>        66 class IPShell:
>        67     """Create an IPython instance."""
>        68
>        69     def
>   **init**(self,argv=None,user_ns=None,user_global_ns=None,
>        70                  debug=1,shell_class=InteractiveShell):
>        71         self.IP = make_IPython(argv,user_ns=user_ns,
>        72                                user_global_ns=user_global_ns,
>   ---> 73 debug=debug,shell_class=shell_class)
>           global that = undefined
>           global gets = undefined
>           global prepended = undefined
>           global to = undefined
>           global all = undefined
>           global calls = undefined
>           global so = undefined
>           global header = undefined
>           global used = undefined
>        74
>        75     def mainloop(self,sys_exit=0,banner=None):
>        76         self.IP.mainloop(banner)
>        77         if sys_exit:
>        78             sys.exit()
>        79
>        80
>
> ## -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> ```
>  81 def kill_embedded(self,parameter_s=''):
>  82     """%kill_embedded : deactivate for good the current
> ```
>
> embedded IPython.
>        83
>        84     This function (after asking for confirmation) sets an
>   internal flag so that
>        85     an embedded IPython will never activate again.  This is useful
>   to
>        86     permanently disable a shell that is being called inside a
>   loop: once you've
>        87     figured out what you needed from it, you may then kill it
>   and the program
>        88     will then continue to run without the interactive shell
>   interfering again.
>
> C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\ipython-0.10-py2.5.egg\IPython
>   \ipmaker.pyc in
>   make_IPython(argv=[r'c:\Python25\Scripts\ipython-
>   script.py', '-i'], user_ns=None,
>   user_global_ns=None, debug=1,
>   rc_override=None, shell_class=,
>   embedded=False, **kw={})
>       755         IP_rc.banner = 0
>       756     if IP_rc.banner:
>       757         BANN_P = IP.BANNER_PARTS
>       758     else:
>       759         BANN_P = []
>       760
>       761     if IP_rc.profile: BANN_P.append('IPython profile: %s\n'
>   % IP_rc.profile)
>       762
>       763     # add message log (possibly empty)
>       764     if msg.summary: BANN_P.append(msg.summary)
>       765     # Final banner is a string
>       766     IP.BANNER = '\n'.join(BANN_P)
>       767
>       768     # Finalize the IPython instance.  This assumes the rc
>   structure is fully
>       769     # in place.
>   --> 770     IP.post_config_initialization()
>       771
>       772     return IP
>       773 #************************ end of file
>
> ---
>
> ```
> 774
> 775
> 776
> 777
> 778
> 779
> 780
> 781
> 782
> 783
> 784
> 785
> ```
>
> C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\ipython-0.10-py2.5.egg\IPython\iplib.pyc
>   in
>   post_config_initialization(self=)
>       847         This is called after the configuration files have been
>   processed to
>       848         'finalize' the initialization."""
>       849
>       850         rc = self.rc
>       851
>       852         # Object inspector
>       853         self.inspector = OInspect.Inspector(OInspect.InspectColors,
>       854 PyColorize.ANSICodeColors,
>       855                                             'NoColor',
>       856 rc.object_info_string_level)
>       857
>       858         self.rl_next_input = None
>       859         self.rl_do_indent = False
>       860         # Load readline proper
>       861         if rc.readline:
>   --> 862             self.init_readline()
>       863
>       864         # local shortcut, this is used a LOT
>       865         self.log = self.logger.log
>       866
>       867         # Initialize cache, set in/out prompts and printing system
>       868         self.outputcache = CachedOutput(self,
>       869                                         rc.cache_size,
>       870                                         rc.pprint,
>       871                                         input_sep = rc.separate_in,
>       872                                         output_sep = rc.separate_out,
>       873                                         output_sep2 = rc.separate_out2,
>       874                                         ps1 = rc.prompt_in1,
>       875                                         ps2 = rc.prompt_in2,
>       876                                         ps_out = rc.prompt_out,
>       877                                         pad_left = rc.prompts_pad_left)
>
> C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\ipython-0.10-py2.5.egg\IPython\iplib.pyc
>   in
>   init_readline(self=)    1476
>   if not readline.uses_libedit:    1477 
>   for rlcommand in
>   self.rc.readline_parse_and_bind:
>   1478                     #print
>   "loading rl:",rlcommand  # dbg    1479
>   readline.parse_and_bind(rlcommand)
>   1480    1481             # Remove some
>   chars from the delimiters list.  If we
>   encounter    1482             #
>   unicode chars, discard them.    1483
>   delims =
>   readline.get_completer_delims().encode("ascii",
>   "ignore")    1484             delims =
>   delims.translate(string._idmap,
>   1485 self.rc.readline_remove_delims)
>   1486
>   readline.set_completer_delims(delims) 
>   1487             # otherwise we end up
>   with a monster history after a while: 
>   1488
>   readline.set_history_length(1000)
>   1489             try:    1490
>
> ## print '*** Reading readline history'  # dbg
>
> -> 1491                 readline.read_history_file(self.histfile)
>   1492             except IOError:
>   1493                 pass  # It
>   doesn't exist yet.    1494    1495
>   atexit.register(self.atexit_operations)
>   1496             del atexit    1497
>   1498         # Configure auto-indent
>   for all platforms    1499
>   self.set_autoindent(self.rc.autoindent)
>   1500    1501     def
>   ask_yes_no(self,prompt,default=True): 
>   1502         if self.rc.quiet:    1503
>   return True    1504         return
>   ask_yes_no(prompt,default)    1505
>   1506     def
>   new_main_mod(self,ns=None):
>
> C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\rlmain.pyc
>   in
>   read_history_file(self=,
>   filename=u'C:\Home\_ipython\history')
>       168
>       169     def set_history_length(self, length):
>       170         '''Set the number of lines to save in the history file.
>       171
>       172         write_history_file() uses this value to truncate the
>   history file
>       173         when saving. Negative values imply unlimited history file
>   size.
>       174         '''
>       175         self._history.set_history_length(length)
>       176
>       177     def clear_history(self):
>       178         '''Clear readline history'''
>       179         self._history.clear_history()
>       180
>       181     def read_history_file(self,
>   filename=None):
>       182         '''Load a readline history file. The default filename is
>   ~/.history.'''
>   --> 183         self._history.read_history_file(filename)
>       184
>       185     def write_history_file(self,
>   filename=None):
>       186         '''Save a readline history file. The default filename is
>   ~/.history.'''
>       187         self._history.write_history_file(filename)
>       188
>       189     #Completer functions
>       190
>       191     def set_completer(self, function=None):
>       192         '''Set or remove the completer function.
>       193
>       194         If function is specified, it will be used as the new
>   completer
>       195         function; if omitted or None, any completer function
>   already
>       196         installed is removed. The completer function is called as
>       197         function(text, state), for state in 0, 1, 2, ..., until it
>   returns a
>       198         non-string value. It should return the next possible
>   completion
>
> C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\lineeditor\history.pyc
>   in
>   read_history_file(self=,
>   filename=u'C:\Home\_ipython\history')
>        55
>        56 history_length=property(get_history_length,set_history_length)
>        57 history_cursor=property(get_history_cursor,set_history_cursor)
>        58
>        59     def clear_history(self):
>        60         '''Clear readline history.'''
>        61         self.history[:] = []
>        62         self.history_cursor = 0
>        63
>        64     def read_history_file(self,
>   filename=None):
>        65         '''Load a readline history file.'''
>        66         if filename is None:
>        67             filename=self.history_filename
>        68         try:
>        69             for line in open(filename, 'r'):
>   ---> 70 self.add_history(lineobj.ReadLineTextBuffer(ensure_unicode(line.rstrip())))
>           global n = undefined
>           global Xd = undefined
>           global S = undefined
>           global NR = undefined
>           global i = undefined
>           global R2 = undefined
>           global R = undefined
>           global t = undefined
>           global history_search_forwardt = undefined
>           global history_search_backwardt = undefined
>           global joinR2 = undefined
>           global maxR = undefined
>           global mint = undefined
>           global IndexError = undefined
>           global RX = undefined
>           global partialt = undefined
>           global hcstartt = undefined
>           global hct = undefined
>           global ht = undefined
>           global result = undefined
>           global s = undefined
>           global C = undefined
>           global Python25 = undefined
>           global lib = undefined
>           global site = undefined
>           global packages = undefined
>           global pyreadline = 
>           global lineeditor = undefined
>           global history.pyt = undefined
>           global *search = undefined
>           global I = undefined
>           global c = undefined
>           global d = undefined
>           global Search = undefined
>           global forward = undefined
>           global through = undefined
>           global the = undefined
>           global history = undefined
>           global string = 
>           global of = undefined
>           global characters = undefined
>           global between = undefined
>           global start = undefined
>           global current = undefined
>           line = 'import sys\n'
>           global point.This = undefined
>           global a = undefined
>           global non = undefined
>           global incremental = undefined
>           global search.By = undefined
>           global default = undefined
>           global this = undefined
>           global command = undefined
>           global unbound.i = undefined
>           global Rj = undefined
>           global Re = undefined
>           global q = undefined
>           global history.pyR* = undefined
>           global backward = undefined
>           global Rk = undefined
>           global history.pyR = undefined
>           global N = undefined
>           global propertyR = undefined
>           global R4 = undefined
>           global R5 = undefined
>           global R7 = undefined
>           global R8 = undefined
>           global RC = undefined
>           global RD = undefined
>           global R_ = undefined
>           global s.t = undefined
>
> Press enter to exit:       global
>   _*main*_t = undefined
>           global aaaat = undefined
>           global aabat = undefined
>           global aacat = undefined
>           global akcat = undefined
>           global bbbt = undefined
>           global ako = undefined
>           global ret = undefined
>           global operatorRS = undefined
>           global sysR = undefined
>           global pyreadline.unicode_helperR = undefined
>           global modulesR = undefined
>           global exceptionst = undefined
>           global ExceptionR = undefined
>           global pyreadline.loggerR = undefined
>           global FalseR9 = undefined
>           global objectR = undefined
>           global RLR = undefined
>           global history.pys = undefined
>           global module = undefined
>        71         except IOError:
>        72             self.history = []
>        73             self.history_cursor = 0
>        74
>        75     def write_history_file(self,
>   filename=None):
>        76         '''Save a readline history file.'''
>        77         if filename is None:
>        78             filename=self.history_filename
>        79         fp = open(filename, 'wb')
>        80         for line in self.history[-self.history_length:]:
>        81             fp.write(ensure_str(line.get_line_text()))
>        82             fp.write('\n')
>        83         fp.close()
>        84
>        85
>
> C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\unicode_helper.pyc
>   in ensure_unicode(text='import sys')
>         5 #  Distributed under the terms of the BSD License.  The full license
>   is in
>         6 #  the file COPYING, distributed as part of this software.
>         7
>
> ## ***********************************************************************
>
> ```
>   8 import sys
>   9
>  10 try:
>  11     pyreadline_codepage=sys.stdout.encoding
>  12 except AttributeError:        #This error occurs when pdb imports readline and doctest has replaced
>  13                               #stdout with stdout collector
>  14     pyreadline_codepage="ascii"   #assume
> ```
>
> ascii codepage
>        15
>        16
>        17 def ensure_unicode(text):
>        18     """helper to ensure that text passed to WriteConsoleW is
>   unicode"""
>        19     if isinstance(text, str):
>   ---> 20         return text.decode(pyreadline_codepage,
>   "replace")
>        21     return text
>        22
>        23 def ensure_str(text):
>        24     """Convert unicode to str using pyreadline_codepage"""
>        25     if isinstance(text, unicode):
>        26         return text.encode(pyreadline_codepage,
>   "replace")
>        27     return text
>        28
>        29
>        30
>        31
>        32
>        33
>        34
>        35
>
> TypeError: decode() argument 1 must be
>   string, not None
>
> ---
>
> Oops, IPython crashed. We do our best
>   to make it stable, but...
>
> A crash report was automatically
>   generated with the following
>   information:
>     - A verbatim copy of the crash traceback.
>     - A copy of your input history during this session.
>     - Data on your current IPython configuration.
>
> It was left in the file named:
>           'C:\Home_ipython\IPython_crash_report.txt'
>   If you can email this file to the
>   developers, the information in it will
>   help them in understanding and
>   correcting the problem.
>
> You can mail it to: Fernando Perez at
>   fperez....@gmail.com with the subject
>   'IPython Crash Report'.
>
> If you want to do it now, the
>   following command will work (under
>   Unix): mail -s 'IPython Crash Report'
>   fperez....@gmail.com <
>   C:\Home_ipython
>   \IPython_crash_report.txt
>
> To ensure accurate tracking of this
>   issue, please file a report about it
>   at:
>   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ipython/+filebug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing [pyreadline](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyreadline) should help.

Comment: But, it seems no In[1]: prompt, only Out[4]: prompt. Please see the output log in the updated question part. Thank you.

Comment: You need to add the Python flags -i and -u to the batch file or command line used to start ipython. That will make it interactive and unbuffered.

Comment: @Dingo, could you give a little more detail about which batch file what do you need to do with it?